# Test coverage with Jacoco plugin for Gradle in offline instrumentation mode for Android

Tags: java, android, ant, jacoco

I'm trying to get code coverage for my PowerMockito unit tests with Jacoco Gradle plugin. I have to use offline instrumentation because PowerMockito doesn't support online mode.

For Jacoco you have to create Ant task which will make code coverage, but all examples of offline instrumentation use **'Java'** plugin which is not compatible with **'com.android.library'** plugin.

Workable solutions which use 'Java' plugin:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'jacoco'

//Additional SourceSets can be added to the jacocoOfflineSourceSets as needed by 
project.ext.jacocoOfflineSourceSets = [ 'main' ]
task doJacocoOfflineInstrumentation(dependsOn: [ classes, project.configurations.jacocoAnt ]) {
    inputs.files classes.outputs.files
    File outputDir = new File(project.buildDir, 'instrumentedClasses')
    outputs.dir outputDir
    doFirst {
        project.delete(outputDir)
        ant.taskdef(
            resource: 'org/jacoco/ant/antlib.xml',
            classpath: project.configurations.jacocoAnt.asPath,
            uri: 'jacoco'
        )
        def instrumented = false
        jacocoOfflineSourceSets.each { sourceSetName ->
            if (file(sourceSets[sourceSetName].output.classesDir).exists()) {
                def instrumentedClassedDir = "${outputDir}/${sourceSetName}"
                ant.'jacoco:instrument'(destdir: instrumentedClassedDir) {
                    fileset(dir: sourceSets[sourceSetName].output.classesDir, includes: '**/*.class')
                }
                //Replace the classes dir in the test classpath with the instrumented one
                sourceSets.test.runtimeClasspath -= files(sourceSets[sourceSetName].output.classesDir)
                sourceSets.test.runtimeClasspath += files(instrumentedClassedDir)
                instrumented = true
            }
        }
        if (instrumented) {
            //Disable class verification based on https://github.com/jayway/powermock/issues/375
            test.jvmArgs += '-noverify'
        }
    }
}
test.dependsOn doJacocoOfflineInstrumentation
```

[Jacoco offline instrumentation Gradle script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41370815/jacoco-offline-instrumentation-gradle-script)

[jacoco code coverage report generator showing error : "Classes in bundle 'Code Coverage Report' do no match with execution data"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31720139/jacoco-code-coverage-report-generator-showing-error-classes-in-bundle-code-c)

For Android I use

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
```

And this plugin doesn't have **'classes'** task, **'jacocoTestReport'** task and have different SourceSet implementation. This error message appears when I try to use both plugins:

```
The 'java' plugin has been applied, but it is not compatible with the Android plugins
```

So, my question is: How to use Jacoco offline instrumentation for Gradle in case of Android platform.

Comment: Found an answer. Just need to use this plugin:
https://github.com/arturdm/jacoco-android-gradle-plugin

Comment: could you please explain how to enable offline instrumentation for github.com/arturdm/jacoco-android-gradle-plugin?

Comment: As far as I remember I just added the mentioned plugin into dependencies. Basically, added an import