# how to prevent jacoco instrumenting production code?

Tags: java, gradle, code-coverage, jacoco, gradle-plugin

i use jacoco plugin for gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin'

jacoco {
    toolVersion = "0.7.9"
}
jacocoTestReport {
    reports {
        xml.enabled true
        html.enabled false
        csv.enabled false
    }
}
```

and then i want to build a package for production

```
./gradlew build jacocoTestReport
```

the question is: will the generated package be instrumented by jacoco? if yes, how can build package NOT instrumented = ready for production? and having code coverage run? do i have to run build twice? is it impossible to build code once (sign it) and then test it, measure coverage etc and if all checks passes, deploy it?

Comment: Why do you run code coverage during a production build anyway?

Comment: to check if it's a shippable build

Comment: IMHO this is usually done with the regular build job and not a release build. Code coverage is about quality and not functionality.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JaCoCo provides two ways of performing instrumentation:

- so-called "on-the-fly" using Java Agent - http://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/agent.html
- and so-called "offline" - http://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/offline.html

The difference is that in first case instrumentation happens in memory during execution and so no class or jar files will be changed on disk - quoting [the second link](http://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/offline.html):

> One of the main benefits of JaCoCo is the Java agent, which instruments classes on-the-fly. This simplifies code coverage analysis a lot as no pre-instrumentation and classpath tweaking is required.

So one of the simplifications that Java agent brings - is exactly that you don't need to worry about packaging or multiple builds. This is IMO one of the advantages of JaCoCo over [other coverage tools for Java](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Code_Coverage_Tools) such as Cobertura and Clover.

And this is one of the reasons why it is highly recommended to use on-the-fly instrumentation - quoting http://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/cli.html :

> the preferred way for code coverage analysis with JaCoCo is on-the-fly instrumentation with the JaCoCo agent. Offline instrumentation has several drawbacks and should only be used if a specific scenario explicitly requires this mode.

One of such specific scenarios - is execution of tests on Android, because there is no way to use Java agent on it. So AFAIK [Android Plugin for Gradle](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html), when instructed to measure coverage using JaCoCo, uses offline instrumentation and therefore requires two types of build - with coverage and without for release.

On the other hand [JaCoCo Gradle Plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/jacoco_plugin.html), which integrates JaCoCo into Gradle for Java projects, [AFAIK](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42238982/244993) as of today provides ability to perform only on-the-fly instrumentation and not offline.

Comment: "requires two types of build - with coverage and without for release." -> Any link on how to configure that exactly?

Comment: @WimDeblauwe just in few clicks from link on Android Plugin for Gradle you can find http://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.BuildType.html#com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.BuildType:testCoverageEnabled "Whether test coverage is enabled for this build type."