# How to add jacocoagent.jar to Android build.gradle - Failed resolution of: Lorg/jacoco/agent/rt/internal_3570298/Offline;

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, jacoco, jacoco-plugin

I have following setup

- AGP 7.x+
- Kotlin 1.5.x+
- JaCoCo 0.8.7+
- Java 11 set as the JDK
- Java 1.8 set as jvmTarget and compileOptions

but when trying to run the AndroidTest and generate jacoco report, it fails with

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/jacoco/agent/rt/internal_3570298/Offline;

After doing my research it seems I need to `add jacocoagent.jar to classpath`, but how?

Tried adding `testImplementation 'org.jacoco:org.jacoco.agent:0.8.7'` and also downloading jar file from search.maven.org/artifact/org.jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/0.8.7/jar and adding `jacoco-agent.properties` file referencing the jar but no success :/ what am I missing...

(things I've looked into:

[Removing Jacoco library dependency while exporting project as jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55301766/removing-jacoco-library-dependency-while-exporting-project-as-jar)

[how to prevent jacoco instrumenting production code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49296416/how-to-prevent-jacoco-instrumenting-production-code)

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37116868 )

Comment: did you get any solution?

Comment: any luck with this, still facing this issue  in AS Android Studio Chipmunk | 2021.2.1 Patch 1

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the correct classifier in the artifact coordinates in order to directly reference the jacocoagent.jar:

```
 [group: 'org.jacoco', name: 'org.jacoco.agent', classifier: 'runtime',
 version: "$JACOCO_VERSION"]
```

As in:

```
configurations {
    ...
    jacocoAgent
    ... }

dependencies {
    ...
    jacocoAgent ([group: 'org.jacoco', name: 'org.jacoco.agent', classifier: 'runtime', version: "..."],)
    ... }
```