# Powermock Jacoco Gradle 0% Coverage For Android Project

Tags: android, offline, powermock, jacoco, instrumentation

We have an Android project, and we're using Powermock for some of our test cases and Jacoco for coverage report.  We noticed that some our classes are returning as **0%** coverage although they are indeed covered. We also observed the message below for affected classes.

```
"Classes ... do no match with execution data."
```

A few searches online show that [Powermock and Jacoco don't play well](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Code-coverage-with-JaCoCo) and that **Offline Instrumentation** is a possible workaround.

Has anyone used gradle Offline Instrumentation script for android projects before?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In hindsight, I guess this can be solved with enough android experience and online perusing. However, I was (and still am) relatively new to Android, gradle, and groovy when this fell on my lap, so I'm writing this for the next me :-D

**WHAT IS HAPPENING IN A NUTSHELL** (*excerpt from a jacoco [forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/jacoco/5IqM4AibmT8/-x5w4kU9BAAJ)*)

- Source file is compiled into non-instrumented class file
- Non-instrumented class file is instrumented (either pre-instrumented offline, or automatically at runtime by Java agent)
- Execution of instrumented classes collected into exec file
- report decorates source files with information obtained from analysis of exec file and original non-instrumented class files
- Message "*`Classes ... do no match with execution data.`*" during generation of report means that class files used for generation of report are not the same as classes prior to instrumentation.

**SOLUTION**

The [Jacoco Offline Instrumentation](https://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/offline.html) page provides the main steps that should occur for offline instrumentation in this excerpt:

> For such scenarios class files can be pre-instrumented with JaCoCo,
>   for example with the instrument Ant task. At runtime the
>   pre-instrumented classes needs be on the classpath instead of the
>   original classes. In addition jacocoagent.jar must be put on the
>   classpath.

The script below does exactly that:

```
    apply plugin: 'jacoco'

configurations {
    jacocoAnt
    jacocoRuntime
}

jacoco {
    toolVersion = "0.8.1"
}

def offline_instrumented_outputDir = "$buildDir.path/intermediates/classes-instrumented/debug"

tasks.withType(Test) {
    jacoco.includeNoLocationClasses = true
}

def coverageSourceDirs = [
        'src/main/java'
]

task jacocoTestReport(type: JacocoReport, dependsOn: "test") {
    group = "Reporting"

    description = "Generate Jacoco coverage reports"

    classDirectories = fileTree(
            dir: 'build/intermediates/classes/debug',
            excludes: ['**/R.class',
                       '**/R$*.class',
                       '**/BuildConfig.*',
                       '**/MainActivity.*']
    )

    sourceDirectories = files(coverageSourceDirs)
    executionData = files('build/jacoco/testDebugUnitTest.exec')
}

jacocoTestReport {
    reports {
        xml.enabled  true
        html.enabled  true
        html.destination file("build/test-results/jacocoHtml")
    }
}

/* This task is used to create offline instrumentation of classes for on-the-fly instrumentation coverage tool like Jacoco. See jacoco classId
     * and Offline Instrumentation from the jacoco site for more info.
     *
     * In this case, some classes mocked using PowerMock were reported as 0% coverage on jacoco & Sonarqube. The issue between PowerMock and jacoco
     * is well documented, and a possible solution is offline Instrumentation (not so well documented for gradle).
     *
     * In a nutshell, this task:
     *  - Pre-instruments the original *.class files
     *  - Puts the instrumented classes path at the beginning of the task's classpath (for report purposes)
     *  - Runs test & generates a new exec file based on the pre-instrumented classes -- as opposed to on-the-fly instrumented class files generated by jacoco.
     *
     * It is currently not implemented to run prior to any other existing tasks (like test, jacocoTestReport, etc...), therefore, it should be called
     * explicitly if Offline Instrumentation report is needed.
     *
     *  Usage: gradle clean & gradle createOfflineInstrTestCoverageReport & gradle jacocoTestReport
     *   - gradle clean //To prevent influence from any previous task execution
     *   - gradle createOfflineInstrTestCoverageReport //To generate *.exec file from offline instrumented class
     *   - gradle jacocoTestReport //To generate html report from newly created *.exec task
     */
task createOfflineTestCoverageReport(dependsOn: ['instrument', 'testDebugUnitTest']) {
    doLast {
        ant.taskdef(name: 'report',
                classname: 'org.jacoco.ant.ReportTask',
                classpath: configurations.jacocoAnt.asPath)
        ant.report() {
            executiondata {
                ant.file(file: "$buildDir.path/jacoco/testDebugUnitTest.exec")
            }
            structure(name: 'Example') {
                classfiles {
                    fileset(dir: "$project.buildDir/intermediates/classes/debug")
                }
                sourcefiles {
                    fileset(dir: 'src/main/java')
                }
            }
            //Uncomment if we want the task to generate jacoco html reports. However, the current script does not exclude files.
            //An alternative is to used jacocoTestReport after this task finishes
            //html(destdir: "$buildDir.path/reports/jacocoHtml")
        }
    }
}

/*
 * Part of the Offline Instrumentation process is to add the jacoco runtime to the class path along with the path of the instrumented files.
 */
gradle.taskGraph.whenReady { graph ->
    if (graph.hasTask(instrument)) {
        tasks.withType(Test) {
            doFirst {
                systemProperty 'jacoco-agent.destfile', buildDir.path + '/jacoco/testDebugUnitTest.exec'
                classpath = files(offline_instrumented_outputDir) + classpath + configurations.jacocoRuntime
            }
        }
    }
}

/*
 *  Instruments the classes per se
 */
task instrument(dependsOn:'compileDebugUnitTestSources') {
    doLast {
        println 'Instrumenting classes'

        ant.taskdef(name: 'instrument',
                classname: 'org.jacoco.ant.InstrumentTask',
                classpath: configurations.jacocoAnt.asPath)

        ant.instrument(destdir: offline_instrumented_outputDir) {
            fileset(dir: "$buildDir.path/intermediates/classes/debug")
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage**

- The script can be copied into a separate file. For instance: `jacoco.gradle`
- Reference the jacoco file in your build.gradle. For instance: `apply from: jacoco.gradle`
- Ensure proper dependencies: `jacocoAnt 'org.jacoco:org.jacoco.ant:0.8.1:nodeps'`
- In command line run: `gradle clean & gradle createOfflineTestCoverageReport & gradle jacocoTestReport`

  `gradle clean` *will wipe out any previous gradle execution artifacts*

  `gradle createOfflineTestCoverageReport` *will create offline instrumentation, change order of classpath, generate .exec file*

  `gradle jacocoTestReport` *will run test and generate jacoco report based on previously generated .exec file*

**Feeling Lost?**

I've put together a github [Jacoco Powermock Android](https://github.com/h8MyJob/PowerMockJacocoDemo/wiki) project with sample scripts to reproduce and fix the issue. It also contains more information about the solution.

**REFERENCE**

```
https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Code-coverage-with-JaCoCo
https://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/classids.html
https://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/offline.html
https://github.com/powermock/powermock-examples-maven/tree/master/jacoco-offline
https://automated-testing.info/t/jacoco-offline-instrumentations-for-android-gradle/20121
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41370815/jacoco-offline-instrumentation-gradle-script/42238982#42238982
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/jacoco/5IqM4AibmT8/-x5w4kU9BAAJ
```

Comment: Not working using gradle build tools 3.2.+
Can you add modification ? thank you